# Width value changes but actual width of div does not

Tags: jquery, css, html, width

I'm working on a much larger project but I simplified it so I could run some tests and try to work through this error. Here is the code I have created for this test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        function browserWidth(){
            $('#bWidth').html( $(window).width() );
            $('#foo').removeAttr();
            $('#foo').attr('width', $(window).width() );
            $('#dWidth').html( $('#foo').attr('width') );
        }
        $(window).resize(browserWidth);
    </script>
    <style>
    body
    {
        background-color: black;
        color: orange;
    }

    #foo
    {
        border-style: outset;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: green;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="foo">
        <h1>H1 text</h1>
        <h2>H2 text</h2>
        <h3>H3 text</h3>
    </div>

    <p>browser width: <span id="bWidth"></span></p>
    <p>div width: <span id="dWidth"></span></p>

</body>
```

the intention of this is to change the width of the div to match that of the current window. if you save this and open it in a browser you'll see the two

tags at the bottom update as the should (with the window width and value of the div's width attribute) but the width of the div remains at 150px (as it was set initially in the #foo css rule). This is especially perplexing because if you inspect the element you can see that the value of the width attribute is changing as the window resizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the style value, not the width attribute

```
jQuery(function () {
    function browserWidth() {
        $('#foo').css('width', $(window).width());
        $('#bWidth').html($(window).width());
        $('#dWidth').html($('#foo').width());
    }
    $(window).resize(browserWidth).resize();//the last call to resize is to trigger a manual resize event so that the initial values will be set properly
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3TEuQ/)

- [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)
- [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2)
- [Document](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) [Ready](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)